# Grouping by with Where conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause, pandas-groupby

Have a dataframe like this:[image]

I created column 'dif_pause' based on subtracting 'pause_end' and 'pause_start' column values and doing the mean value aggregation using groupby () function just like this:

```
pauses['dif_pause'] = pauses['pause_end'] - pauses['pause_start']
pauses['dif_pause'].astype(dt.timedelta).map(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else x.days)

pauses_df=pauses.groupby(["subscription_id"])["dif_pause"].mean().reset_index(name="avg_pause")
```

I'd like to include in the groupby section the checking whether pause_end>pause_start (some equialent of WHERE clause in SQL). How can one do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you need [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first for filtering:

```
pauses.query("pause_end > pause_start")
       .groupby(["subscription_id"])["dif_pause"].mean().reset_index(name="avg_pause")
```

---

```
pauses[pauses["pause_end"] > pauses["pause_start"]]
      .groupby(["subscription_id"])["dif_pause"].mean().reset_index(name="avg_pause")
```