# DataFrame difference between where and query

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I was able to solve a problem with pandas thanks to the answer provided in [Grouping by with Where conditions in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537249/grouping-by-with-where-conditions-in-pandas).

I was first trying to make use of the `.where()` function like the following:

```
df['X'] = df['Col1'].where(['Col1'] == 'Y').groupby('Z')['S'].transform('max').astype(int)
```

but got this error: *ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self*

By writing it like

```
df['X'] = df.query('Col1 == "Y"').groupby('Z')['S'].transform('max').astype(int)
```

it worked.

I'm trying to understand what is the difference as I thought `.where()` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your first statement. `.where(['Col1'] == 'Y')` is comparing a single element list with 'Y'.  I think  you meant to use `.where(df['Col1'] == 'Y'`, however, this will not work either because you filtering dataframe columns to just 'Col1' in front of the where method.  This is what you really wanted to do, in my opinion.

```
df['X'] = df.where(df['Col1'] == 'Y').groupby('Z')['S'].transform('max')
```

Which is equalivant to using

```
df['X'] = df.query('Col1 == "Y"').groupby('Z')['S'].transform('max').astype(int)
```

Also, not the `astype(int)` is not going to do any good on either of these statements because one side effect in pandas is that any column with a 'int' dtype that contains a NaN will automatically change that column to a 'float'.