# Creating a new pandas column which takes values from a row, based on id

Tags: python, pandas

How do I go about doing the follwing in a pandas dataframe? I have a time-series where I want a new column created that's based on having the same id value it looks for the previous epoch's value. See picture. I would like to do the following:

1. Create new column called `previous_epoch_stage`.
2. For each `id`:

- fill `previous_epoch_stage` column with `stage` value from epoch-1 row.
- but if epoch == 1 then fill `previous_epoch_stage` value with `stage` value from the same row.

[image]

Comment: You can use the `shift` function to get the value of the row above, like `df['previous_epoch_stage'] = df['stage'].shift(1)`. After that just write the `stage` value if `df[]époch']==1`.

Comment: But it also needs to match this with id otherwise it can go to a previous row with a different id

Comment: Usually when you want to say *"do some assignment on a per-group basis"* the answer is `df.groupby()` or logical indexing (index `df[df['epoch'!=1]`). Here, you want to access the lagged value of `df['stage'].shift(`)`.

Comment: Take a skim of the [pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) on Selection, Indexing and selecting data, Grouping, Working with missing data... That's your basic Swiss-army-knife toolkit for doing lots of powerful stuff.

Comment: Also we can shortcut *"fill `previous_epoch_stage` column with `stage` value from epoch-1 row"* if we assume/require rows are sorted in increasing `epoch` starting from 1, then we can just take `df['stage'].head()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you **don't need to create extra columns, if all you want is to access a lagged version of `epoch`**. You'd simply do `df.groupby('id')` then reference `['epoch'].shift(1)` within each grouped-dataframe.

But if you really insist on doing this, **solution using [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html?highlight=boolean%20indexing), [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)** :

```
# Do the default lagged assignment for all rows where 'epoch' != 1
df['previous_epoch_stage'] = df.groupby('id')['epoch'].shift(1)
# Now fill NA's in-place from the 'stage' column
df['previous_epoch_stage'].fillna(df['stage'], inplace=True)
# and if you want to reverse fillna and the NaNs coercing your ints to floats:
df['previous_epoch_stage'] = df['previous_epoch_stage'].astype(int)
```

Notes:

1. we can shortcut "fill `previous_epoch_stage` column with `stage` value from epoch-1 row" if we assume/require rows are sorted in increasing `epoch` starting from 1, then we can just take `df['stage'].head()`
2. there's also a useful helper function `df.where(cond, other, ...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) that does vectorized if-else, and in this case `other` would need to be a function ('callable'), but [it doesn't play nicely with groupby, so use boolean indexing instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537249/grouping-by-with-where-conditions-in-pandas).
3. [.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) is neat because it allows you to customize `fill_value=NaN`, or specify arbitrary `periods` (+ve or -ve).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a more Pandas solution, but another solution could be:

```
df['prev_epoch_stage']=[df['stage'].iloc[i-1] if e>1 else df['stage'].iloc[i]
                        for i,e in enumerate(epoch)]
```

Comment: But how would it know only to do this if the id matches?

Comment: Then change it to something like `df['stage'].iloc[i-1] if e>1 and df['id'].iloc[i-1]==df['id'].iloc[i] else df['stage'].iloc[i]`

Comment: I think i understand the logic of this but I am not sure how to declare what is i and e...

Comment: `df['col'].iloc[i-1] ` is just `df['col'].shift()` in disguise. [.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) is nicer because it allows you to customize `fill_value=NaN`.

Comment: @Apavlo: i,e are the variables iterated by [enumerate()](https://pythonbasics.org/enumerate/)