# Min of a column if another column is above average

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some Python exercises and I'm stuck with a question.

I'm using the following Titanic dataframe: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NEHvlUMTNPusHZvHUFTqeUR_9yY1tHVz/view

Now I need to find the minimum value of the column 'Age' for each class of 'Pclass' for the passengers that paid a fare ('Fare') above the average.

Using this I can get the minimum age by group, but how can I add the 'above average Fare' condition to this?

```
df.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].min()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can:

1. find mean
2. filter
3. pivot_table, minimum value of the column 'Age' for each class of 'Pclass'

   ```
   avrg_Fare = df['Fare'].mean()
   df = df.loc[df['Fare'] > avrg_Fare]
   PVT_min_age = df.pivot_table(index='Pclass', aggfunc={'Age':np.min}).reset_index()
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I At the end I created another df with only ppl that paid above average fares (as yous suggested) and used the code from my example to get the minimum ages.

Comment: Very good, please rate my comment :). It will affect my motivation.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a shot

```
 average_fare = df['Fare'].mean()
    
df.query("fare > @average_fare").groupby('Pclass_2').agg{'Age': ['min']}
```

[Grouping by with Where conditions in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537249/grouping-by-with-where-conditions-in-pandas)

I may have some syntax errors since its been awhile since i've done pandas, if anyone sees a problem please correct it

Comment: It returns the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'

Comment: maybe try that edit but just have a look at query groupby and aggregates should get you wherre you need to